css modules import order with vite and mantine themed components
having an issue where I have a monorepo with turborepo using vite as the build system.
I have a UI package and a react app package. The UI package includes custom components as well as themed mantine components i.e. using the styles/props api to set default classnames, props etc.
These extended components are imported into the mantine theme object within this components library package. i.e.
import {
  AlertExtend,
  ActionIconExtend,
} from "../../";

components: {
    ActionIcon: ActionIconExtend(),
    Alert: AlertExtend(),
  },

These components use css modules, and the css modules are bundled in with the components using vite and vite-plugin-lib-inject-css.
The issue I have is that when importing and using any of these extended components into my application the app fails to render as the css class names declaration in the bundled .js files is happening after the mantine theme.
So the mantine theme calls ActionIconExtend() and in the browser I see ReferenceError: Cannot access 'u' before initialization looking at the bundled source code this is because of the class names and how they are ordered i.e.
F = "_root_1s03r_1"
j = "_icon_1s03r_20"

u = {
  root: F,
  icon: j
}

ActionIcon: ActionIconExtend() is being called before the above u object is declared.
I am not sure of a way around this. I do not think there is anyway to control the bundled output order.
